# Horizontal data or vertical data which is the better one in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables. Each table contains companies profit from January to April. For simplicity I have used month names in table1.

1) which table is better than the other?

2) I would like to find cummulative sum for each company from Jan to April.

```
#standardSQL
with table1 as(
select "A" as comapany, 345 as Jan, 456 as Feb, 543 as March, 987 as April union all
select "B", 405, 956, 673, 907 union all
select "C", 745, 476, 323, 477
)
select * from table1

(or)

#standardSQL
with table2 as(
select  345 as A_profit, 456 as B_profit, 543 as C_profit,"1-31-2017" as year union all
select  405 , 956, 673,"2-28-2017" union all
select  745 , 476, 323,"3-31-2017" union all
select  515 , 736, 833,"4-30-2017"
)
select * from table2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which table is better than the other?

None are prefect or even good :o(
Below is what I would recommended to support most generic cases with dynamic number of companies and arbitrary time frame, etc.
But I can admit that if you have very specific case with just few companies and very specific short time frame - you might find either of table1 or table2 somehow useful - but I doubt it can be a practical real life case

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table3 AS(
  SELECT "A" AS company, 345 AS profit, '1-31-2017' AS profit_date UNION ALL
  SELECT "A", 456, '2-28-2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT "A", 543, '3-31-2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT "A", 987, '4-30-2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT "B", 405, '1-31-2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT "B", 956, '2-28-2017' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "B", 673, '3-31-2017' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "B", 907, '4-30-2017' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 745, '1-31-2017' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 476, '2-28-2017' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 323, '3-31-2017' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 477, '4-30-2017' 
)
```

please note - i am not changing here data types and use as in your original examples - which is `STRING` for dates

this will end up with below query to get

> ... cumulative sum for each company from Jan to April

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT company, SUM(profit) profit
FROM table3
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%m-%d-%Y', profit_date) 
  BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2017-04-30' 
GROUP BY company
```

with result as

```sql
Row company profit   
1   A       2331     
2   B       2941     
3   C       2021
```

To avoid that extra parsing string to date - you can rather use `DATE` types as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table4 AS(
  SELECT "A" AS company, 345 AS profit, DATE '2017-01-31' AS profit_date UNION ALL
  SELECT "A", 456, DATE '2017-02-28' UNION ALL
  SELECT "A", 543, DATE '2017-03-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT "A", 987, DATE '2017-04-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT "B", 405, DATE '2017-01-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT "B", 956, DATE '2017-02-28' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "B", 673, DATE '2017-03-31' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "B", 907, DATE '2017-04-30' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 745, DATE '2017-01-31' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 476, DATE '2017-02-28' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 323, DATE '2017-03-31' UNION ALL 
  SELECT "C", 477, DATE '2017-04-30' 
)
SELECT company, SUM(profit) profit
FROM table4
WHERE profit_date
  BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2017-04-30' 
GROUP BY company
```

obviously with the same very result